# Building ros hydro from source on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgraded a Ubuntu 13.10 system that had Hydro built from source to Ubuntu 14.04, and encountered the following issues:

**rosdep**

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
roslaunch: No definition of [python-paramiko] for OS version [trusty]
qt_dotgraph: No definition of [python-pydot] for OS version [trusty]
rosgraph: No definition of [python-mock] for OS version [trusty]
rosdoc_lite: No definition of [python-sphinx] for OS version [trusty]
opencv2: No definition of [python-support] for OS version [trusty]
rqt_plot: No definition of [python-qt-bindings-qwt5] for OS version [trusty]
ps3joy: No definition of [python-bluez] for OS version [trusty]
wiimote: No definition of [python-cwiid] for OS version [trusty]
rqt_top: No definition of [python-psutil] for OS version [trusty]
roswtf: No definition of [python-paramiko] for OS version [trusty]
rqt_pose_view: No definition of [python-qt-bindings-gl] for OS version [trusty]
python_orocos_kdl: No definition of [python-sip] for OS version [trusty]
rviz: No definition of [libogre-dev] for OS version [trusty]
```

I think because all the dependencies were still lying around and installed from when rosdep worked fully in 13.10, I was able to skip over this.

**Gazebo**

It was (obvious in retrospect)  necessary to rebuild gazebo, which I had built from source earlier, not doing this produced an error saying protobuf header files needed to be regenerated with protoc

**catkin_make**

I attempted to run the catkin_make command after that in the same workspace as had been used when the system was 13.10, but encountered difficulties with libqhull, libyaml-cpp, and libprotobuf- I think they all had version upticks for 14.04 which move the .so symlink to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  from /usr/lib, but the old .so.x.y libs were still there in /usr/lib.

Errors produced were of the sort:

```
/include/gazebo-2.2/gazebo/msgs/axis.pb.h:19:2: error: #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
 #error regenerate this file with a newer version of protoc.
...
undefined reference to `YAML::Node::Node()'
```

Maybe I should have run a catkin_make clean or similar but I ended up just starting over in a new catkin workspace, which built fine.

I haven't tested the built result much, and I'm pretty sure the build process would fail on a fresh 14.04 install due to the rosdep issue at the top here, but I'll try that eventually unless someone else documents it first.

**Ogre**

```
/usr/include/CEGUI/RendererModules/Ogre/CEGUIOgreRenderer.h:57:7: error: using typedef-name ‘Ogre::TexturePtr’ after ‘class’
class TexturePtr;
```

This has the workaround:
​
http://cegui.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=6555#p30834
in /usr/include/CEGUI/RendererModules/Ogre/CEGUIOgreRenderer.h replace

```
class TexturePtr
```

with

```
class Texture;
template<typename T> class SharedPtr;
typedef SharedPtr<Texture> TexturePtr;
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156416/building-ros-hydro-from-source-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what the issue is with your rosdep, but I have built all of desktop-full hydro on my fresh 14.04 machine after having built and installed gazebo and collada-dom from source.

Try updating `rosdep` and try again.

Also, it should be noted, Hydro isn't supported on Trusty, if it happen to build that's great, but we don't plan to spend a large amount of time maintaining it for Trusty. Indigo should be spun up relatively soon, like within a few months.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1